# Call same function before every test case in python unittest framework

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there any way to call same function before every testcase in python unittest framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should investigate [setUp()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp)

> setUp()
>
> Method called to prepare the test fixture. 
>   This is called immediately before calling the test method; any exception raised by
>   this method will be considered an error rather than a test failure.
>   The default implementation does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [`setUp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) method of your `unittest.TestCase` subclass is for.